# Using LINQ to organize database result

Tags: .net, sql-server, linq

I have a problem in a Film/Movie Management System. I have tables,

Table **Films**

```
+----+------------------+---------------------------+
| Id | Name             | Description               |
+----+------------------+---------------------------+
| 1  | Kabaddi Kabaddi  |Kabaddi Kabaddi is a...    |
| 2  | Kabaddi          |Kabaddi is a...            |
| 3  | Jholay           |A man hopes to achieve...  |
| 4  | Nai Nabhannu La  |                           |
+----+------------------+---------------------------+
```

Table **Roles**

```
+----+----------+
| Id | Name     |
+----+----------+
| 1  | Actor    |
| 2  | Actress  |
| 3  | Director |
+----+----------+
```

Table **People**

```
+----+--------------+---------------+-----------+
| Id | FirstName    | MiddleName    | LastName  |
+----+--------------+---------------+-----------+
| 1  | Dayahang     |               | Rai       |
| 2  | Priyanka     |               | Karki     |
| 3  | Nischal      |               | Basnet    |
+----+--------------+---------------+-----------+
```

Table **Casts**

```
+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| FilmId    | PersonId  | RoleId    |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| 1         | 1         | 1         |
| 2         | 1         | 1         |
| 3         | 1         | 1         |
| 2         | 3         | 1         |
| 1         | 3         | 1         |
| 2         | 3         | 3         |
| 1         | 3         | 3         |
| 4         | 2         | 2         |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+
```

My goal is to get the list of movies with respective casts with respective roles with a single query.

```
Kabaddi Kabaddi <FilmName>
    Dayahang <CastFirstName>
        Actor <RoleName>
    Nischal <CastFirstName>
        Actor <RoleName>
        Director <RoleName>
Jholay <FilmName>
    Dayahang <CastFirstName>
        Actor <RoleName>
    Priyanka <CastFirstName>
        Actress <RoleName>
```

Best I have tried is

```
var result = from cast in entity.Casts
             join film in entity.Films on cast.FilmId equals film.Id
             join person in entity.People on cast.PersonId equals person.Id
             join role in entity.Roles on cast.RoleId equals role.Id
```

which results

```
+-------------------+---------------+-----------+
| FilmName          | CastFirstName | RoleName  |
+-------------------+---------------+-----------+
| Kabaddi Kabaddi   | Dayahang      | Actor     |
| Kabaddi           | Dayahang      | Actor     |
| Jholay            | Dayahang      | Actor     |
| Kabaddi           | Nischal       | Actor     |
| Kabaddi Kabaddi   | Nischal       | Actor     |
| Kabaddi           | Nischal       | Director  |
| Kabaddi Kabaddi   | Nischal       | Director  |
| Nai Nabhannu La   | Nischal       | Actress   |
+-------------------+---------------+-----------+
```

Is it possible in a single query? How?

Comment: But it is a single query...

Comment: Don't you already have your answer with your own code? What is the problem?

Comment: But the FilmName are repeating. I need it in the order mentioned after "My goal is to get the list of movies ..." in the post.

Comment: A SQL query always returns data in tabular format, if you mean you want a list of strings that look like below that line then it might be possible to use T-SQL or stored procedure but not single query. But why not use loops to generate the list from the returned table?

Answer (score 0):

I hope, something like this should help to get started (please excuse syntax and typo):

```
from cast in entity.Casts
             join film in entity.Films on cast.FilmId equals film.Id
             join person in entity.People on cast.PersonId equals person.Id
             join role in entity.Roles on cast.RoleId equals role.Id
group new { cast, film, person, role} by film into grp
                    select new
                    {
                        Film = grp.Key.Name,
                        Persons= grp.Select(r => new People()
                        {
                            Id = r.People.Id
                        }),
                        Roles = grp.Select(r => new Role()
                        {
                            Id = r.role.Id
                        })
                    };
```